# What are custom dot (.) references in helm templates (similar to .Values and .Chart) doing and how are they defined?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have a helm chart that is using some kind of custom template references (as far as I understand). This is the `.tpl` file:

```golang
{{- define "common.secret._header" -}}
{{- $global := .global }}
{{- $name := .name }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ $name }}
  namespace: {{ include "common.namespace" $global }}
  labels:
    app: {{ include "common.name" $global }}
    chart: {{ $global.Chart.Name }}-{{ $global.Chart.Version | replace "+" "_" }}
    release: {{ include "common.release" $global }}
    heritage: {{ $global.Release.Service }}
{{- end -}}
```

I am used to having the predefined `.Values` or `.Release` template references, but I have never seen the `.global` or `.name` references before. I guess they are custom defined versions of the same concept.

Can someone explain the general mechanism behind this and how they are assigned?

Comment: A `define` template takes a single parameter, which is `.`.  So `.global` is a "named parameter" more or less from a call like `{{ include "common.secret._header" (dict "global" .Values.global "name" "some-name") }}`.  Other things can be `.` too, and the linked question has more details.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze. So in your example, the `(dict ...)` is defining the parameter for that `include`, right? Now that you say it, I have found this being used as `{{ include "common.secret._header" (dict "global" . "name" "myName") }}` in my chart. Can you say a word about the `.Values.global` that you have included in your example?

Comment: Correct, in that invocation the `(dict ...)` is the parameter, and inside the called template that appears as `.`.  `.Values.global` refers to, well, a block named `global` in the `values.yaml` file, but it's propagated into dependency charts; also see [Global Values](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#global-values) in the Helm documentation.